# How to create an object in ActiveRecord without initialize method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, initialization

Consider a model without an initialize method, defined as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
end
```

It has 2 properties: `name` & `age`.

It is possible to create a new object by calling `User.new('Joe Brown', 21)`? Is there another "shorthand" way of creating the object?

Or do you have to define an initialize method in order to do this in one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ActiveRecord:

```
User.new(:name => "Joe Brown", :age => 21)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the fields :

```
User.new :name => "Joe Brown", :age => 21
```

or

```
User.new name: "Joe Brown", age: 21
```

Answer (score 2):

`User.create(:name => "Joe Brown", :age => 21)` will create ***and*** save the object. (AR).